# UIImageView with another UIImage of frame

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

i m developing an photo based app
i have two imageview one imageview contains the original image
and other imageview contains the frame

Now the problem is i want to manage the frame Imageview according to the main image
i.e. if my main image view is of size 320x480 then border applies on that size 
and if my image view is of size 200x150 then border have to applies on that size

How to do that

Answer (score 0):

UIImage.size can give you dimensions of image you are using. you can resize your UIImageView.frame using this size. this will fit UIImage in UIImageView without any extra space so borders will appear perfect.

second option could be to initialize an image view once again using following method.

`- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image`

this will make a perfect sized imageview for your image.

Let me know if you are not looking for something like this....

Comment: my images are high resolution image so the size can be 2532x3000 something so i can not give the size of image to my view